# Trying to run MDSCHEMA_SETS but getting a failure

Tags: ssis, ssas, ssms, ssas-2012

I am trying to run this command either through SSIS (execute ddl) or a SSMS Job step using the Analysis Services Command. It works fine through management studio xmla query window though.

```
<Discover xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
    <RequestType>MDSCHEMA_SETS</RequestType>
    <Restrictions />
    <Properties />
</Discover>
```

I get the following error:

Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaException: The Discover element at line 7, column 72 (namespace urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis) cannot appear under Envelope/Body/Execute/Command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to work through an SSIS Script task.

```
string servername = Dts.Variables["$Project::SSAS_QueryServerName"].Value.ToString();
XmlaClient clnt = new XmlaClient();
clnt.Connect(servername);
string xmla = "<Discover xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis\"> \r\n" +
@"<RequestType>MDSCHEMA_SETS</RequestType>
<Restrictions />
<Properties />
</Discover>";
clnt.Send( xmla, null );
clnt.Disconnect();
```